# How to use word2vec and RNN together?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, word2vec, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network

So, I am using word2vec in Java, and trying to train it somehow so that it gives me vector representation for words and sentences.

Can I use this for feeding input into a neural network, to get a response on the basis of the word2vec data? I am planning to make a chatbot with the help of this.

Comment: So you want to get a vector representation for a word using word2vec and then use that vector as input to an RNN? In a way that the word2vec acts like an embedding function for the RNN but training it separately? Or jointly?

Comment: I think using that as an input to RNN would be more beneficial. I want to train them jointly. What do you think? What would be a better approach? @galloguille Great if you could help me out with this.

Comment: Well, I don't know that much about NLP, but I guess you could use a pretrained word2vec to generate word embeddings and then use that embeddings as the input to the RNN, so you wouldn't need to train the word2vec yourself.

Comment: But even for getting the embeddings from words as vectors, I will need to train my word2vec, and then use that as an input to RNN for training. Isnt it?

Comment: Well ypu can use a pre-trained word2vec, so you would only need to train the RNN with the vectors as inputs.

Comment: But can I find pretrained word2vec for sentences/messages, because while I was finding reference on the internet, most of them are for words. Could you suggest me someone who could help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to @galloguille's comments, you can use pre-trained word2vec's word-vectors to initialize your RNN. RNN can learn from sequence of words to predict next word(s). A good example with code for this, you can find here - https://github.com/larspars/word-rnn.

There is good collection of current state of the art on chatbots here - https://stanfy.com/blog/the-rise-of-chat-bots-useful-links-articles-libraries-and-platforms/

From my understanding, most effective chatbots don't use RNN directly (at present) to reply to a question, but try to predict intent (from a fixed set of intents) of the question in the first step. Based on each intent, they calculate some actionable insights and a logical reply to the question.

Comment: what would be the best approach to do it then? Instead of RNN?

Comment: RNN is good approach if you want to play around with text generation with deep learning. But if you are looking to deploy a chatbot in real world application, deep learning is not there yet. You have to hardcode possible intents of the user (based on the use-case) and match each question to the intent, and then again hard-code a fixed set of responses for the particular question.